# C# Mongo FirstOrDefaultAsync hangs

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver

using the 2.0 driver the following code will sometimes hang and never return.

```
public async Task<T> GetFirst(FilterDefinition<T> query)
{
    return await GetCollection.Find(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

if I debut and put a break point on the return line, everything returns normally.  In the shell the query being run is something like this:

```
db.Customers.find({"Name" : /test$/i})
```

Comment: You probably need to add a ConfigureAwait to the end of the call so that you don't deadlock your main thread.

return await GetCollection.Find(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: However, in this case, there really isn't any reason you need to use the async and await keywords...  just return GetCollection.Find(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: removing the async and await worked... not sure why, I assumed because it was FirstOrDefaultAsync it needed an await flag

Comment: How exactly are you calling `GetFirst()`? Are you using something like `GetFirst(query).Result`?

Comment: I call the GetFirst with the await flag, so something like this  await repo.GetFirst(filterQuery);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Add a `ConfigureAwait(false)` at the end:

   ```
   return await GetCollection.Find(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```
2. Just return the `Task<T>`, since the result of `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is the same type as the result you want to return.

   ```
   public Task<T> GetFirst(FilterDefinition<T> query)
   {
       return GetCollection.Find(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
   }
   ```