# Avoiding deadlocks while keeping async i/o in MongoDB Find call

Tags: c#, mongodb, wcf

Using an async Find call in a WCF application (C# MongoDB Driver v2.2.2.10) causes timeouts from time to time.

This is what we use today:

```
  public static async Task<T> FindOne<T>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection, FilterDefinition<T> filter = null, FindOptions options = null,
            CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class
        {
            return await collection.Find(filter, options).FirstOrDefaultAsync(token);
        }
```

However, this tends to hang and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656923/c-sharp-mongo-firstordefaultasync-hangs) says I should add ConfigureAwait(false):

```
return await collection.Find(filter, options).FirstOrDefaultAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My question is, in a WCF context, is using ConfigureAwait(false) safe in an application that is heavily multi threaded?

Comment: Where does it timeout? Driver? or even your code. Since it's multi-threaded app, it could be anywhere. I'd suggest to revisit what are you doing carefully and take advantage of profiling.

Comment: Saleem, thank you, this is indeed all over the place, I am trying to see first if there's an error in the way we invoke this call.

Comment: Oh I see, you are using `collection.Find` which is blocking call. Replace it with `FindAsync`

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/#query-for-all-documents-in-a-collection

Comment: @Saleem this is incorrect, they are both Async, one returns all the documents and one (FindAsync) returns a cursor

Comment: This is the point. All vs cursor. Think if you have thousands of documents what will happen.

Comment: @Saleem #facepalm thanks for the wake up call

Comment: You are welcome, It's community of helping hands and glad it worked for you. so no #facepalm but #smile.